# Where am I going wrong with this menu

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

I have created a code for a menu system for my coin counter, I'm trying to make it so the user can choose more than one option after they have chosen the first until they decide to end the program. It doesn't loop and the code only runs one option then I have to restart the code manually via run on eclipse. Anyone could give me some insight into what I have missed here, thank you:)

```
Scanner ss=new Scanner(System.in);
int Choice;
int opt;
    System.out.println("***Coin Sorter - Main Menu***");
    System.out.println("    1 - Coin Calculator");
    System.out.println("    2 - Multiple coin calculator");
    System.out.println("    3 - Print Coin list");
    System.out.println("    4 - Set details");
    System.out.println("    5 - Display program configurations");
    System.out.println("    6 - Quit the program");
    Choice=ss.nextInt();
    switch(Choice) {
        case 1: coinCalculator();
                break;
        case 2: multiCoinCalculator();
                break;
        case 3: printCoinList();
                break;
        case 4: System.out.println("***Set Details Sub-Menu***");
                System.out.println("1 - Set currency");
                System.out.println("2 - Set minimum coin input value");
                System.out.println("3 - Set maximum coin input value");
                System.out.println("4 - Return to main menu");
                opt=ss.nextInt();
                if (opt==1) {
                setCurrency(Currency);
                }else if (opt==2) {
                    setMinCoinin(opt);
                }else if (opt==3) {
                    setMaxCoinin(opt);
                }else if (opt==4);
                    CoinSorter();
                break;
        case 5: displayProgramConfigs();
                break;
        case 6: if(Choice != 6) System.out.println("Unkown option");    
    } while (Choice !=6);
```

Comment: Try wrapping your code into a [do-while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and adding an exit option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `default` for `Unkown option`. Learn more about it from the tutorial, **[The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)**
2. Put the menu inside a `do-while` loop properly. You have missed `do` in your code.
3. You have wrongly put a `;` after `else if (opt==4)`

Last but not least, always follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of the variable can be `choice` but should not be `Choice`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        int opt;
        do {
            System.out.println("***Coin Sorter - Main Menu***");
            System.out.println("    1 - Coin Calculator");
            System.out.println("    2 - Multiple coin calculator");
            System.out.println("    3 - Print Coin list");
            System.out.println("    4 - Set details");
            System.out.println("    5 - Display program configurations");
            System.out.println("    6 - Quit the program");
            choice = ss.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                coinCalculator();
                break;
            case 2:
                multiCoinCalculator();
                break;
            case 3:
                printCoinList();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("***Set Details Sub-Menu***");
                System.out.println("1 - Set currency");
                System.out.println("2 - Set minimum coin input value");
                System.out.println("3 - Set maximum coin input value");
                System.out.println("4 - Return to main menu");
                opt = ss.nextInt();
                if (opt == 1) {
                    setCurrency(Currency);
                } else if (opt == 2) {
                    setMinCoinin(opt);
                } else if (opt == 3) {
                    setMaxCoinin(opt);
                } else if (opt == 4) {
                    CoinSorter();
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                displayProgramConfigs();
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Good Bye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unkown option");
            }
        } while (choice != 6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is running infinite, you have to use do-while to resolve the issue.

```
Scanner ss=new Scanner(System.in);
int Choice;
int opt;
do {
    System.out.println("***Coin Sorter - Main Menu***");
    System.out.println("    1 - Coin Calculator");
    System.out.println("    2 - Multiple coin calculator");
    System.out.println("    3 - Print Coin list");
    System.out.println("    4 - Set details");
    System.out.println("    5 - Display program configurations");
    System.out.println("    6 - Quit the program");
    Choice=ss.nextInt();
    switch(Choice) {
        case 1: coinCalculator();
                break;
        case 2: multiCoinCalculator();
                break;
        case 3: printCoinList();
                break;
        case 4: System.out.println("***Set Details Sub-Menu***");
                System.out.println("1 - Set currency");
                System.out.println("2 - Set minimum coin input value");
                System.out.println("3 - Set maximum coin input value");
                System.out.println("4 - Return to main menu");
                opt=ss.nextInt();
                if (opt==1) {
                    setCurrency(Currency);
                }else if (opt==2) {
                    setMinCoinin(opt);
                }else if (opt==3) {
                    setMaxCoinin(opt);
                }else if (opt==4);
                    CoinSorter();
                break;
        case 5: displayProgramConfigs();
                break;
        case 6: if(Choice != 6) System.out.println("Unkown option");    
    } 

} while (Choice !=6);
```

It will run correctly.